# Simple Multiplicity in Relational Database ER Diagram

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm trying to design a database for a duty roster but i'm struggling with the multiplicity on the ER diagram.

Here is the section i'm struggling with:

[image]

The DutyRoster table in the database will act as a huge link table that joins the members with an event and a duty.

Therefore, it will contain many records for each staff member, many for each records per event (one for each staff member) and many records for each duty. How is this represented using the multiplicity? Is each link a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: What is the link between Event and EventDuty? Namingwise i feel tehre is a Duty entity missing. I would expect EventDuty to be a link between Event and Duty, or if duties differ much per event, i would expect a simple 1-n relation between Event and EventDuty. That would definitely make your model more logical...

Comment: There is no relationship between the two. EventDuty is just a list of possible duties such as 'Leader' or 'Cleaner'. The dutys are the same for each event, but the number of staff doing each one may differ. Does that help?

Comment: ok, then indeed each link in your model is a 1-many link towards DutyRoster. And that creates a many-to-many relationship between EventDuty, Event and Staff.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you've cleared things up in my head now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've currently modelled this (with the FK's), an Instance DutyRoster consists of exactly one Event, one Staff-member and one EventDuty.

As I'm understanding this whole ER, the multiplicities should be as follows:

```
DutyRoster * -------- 1 Event
DutyRoster * -------- 1 Staff
DutyRoster * -------- 1 EventDuty
```

Comment: An instance being one row in the database? If so, then one instance will indeed contain one event, one staff member and one duty. When writing an ER do the multiplicities apply to one instance or one entity?

Comment: You can basically read the first entry like this:
One DutyRoster is in relation with 1 Event
One Event is in relation with 0..multiple(*) DutyRosters